# How to execute a find command using a set of strings from a line in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

This is the content of my text file named fnames.txt:

```
"SAMPLE_NIKE_856_20170703*"
"SAMPLE_ADIDAS_856_20170702*"
"SAMPLE_ANTA_856_20170630*"
"SAMPLE_JORDAN_856_20170627*"
"SAMPLE_CONVERSE_856_20170229*"
```

This is my script named fn.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
while read LINE
do
    find -name "$LINE"
done < fnames.txt
```

It returns nothing.

What I want to happen is that in each line the script will execute the find command and the output will be stored in another text file called files.txt e.g:

LINE 1:

```
find -name "SAMPLE_NIKE_856_20170703*"
```

then returns the filename that is looking for

```
./SAMPLE_NIKE_856_20170703_80_20_304_234_897.dat
```

LINE 2:

```
find -name "SAMPLE_ADIDAS_856_20170702*
```

then returns the filename that is looking for

```
./SAMPLE_ADIDAS_856_20170702_56_98_123_245_609.dat
```

The script will continue until all lines has been executed by find command.

Comment: First your script should return the same results to the standard output as the separate calls of `find`, if you run your script in the right directory. Secondly, to store the results in a text file you can add `echo "$Line" >> out.txt` to your loop.

Comment: I can not understand on what you said "script should return the same results to the standard output as the separate calls of find". Can you provide and example?

Comment: What's the shell that you're using ? What's your OS ?

Comment: It's BASH #!/bin/sh. I'm using Linux through PuTTY cause my pc OS is Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I just need to call the full file path of fnames.txt to /path/to/my/fnames.txt because I'm executing the script in another directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
while read -r LINE
do
    find -name "$LINE"
done < /path/to/my/fnames.txt
```

Output:

```
./SAMPLE_NIKE_856_20170703_80_20_304_234_897.dat
./SAMPLE_ADIDAS_856_20170702_56_98_123_245_609.dat
```

Comment: "...I just need to call the full file path of fnames.txt..." that is exactly what I'm trying to tell you in my first point in the comment above with respect to your question. That certainly you run your script in the wrong directory!

Comment: Sorry didn't understand that part, that's why I ask. Thanks for the help by the way.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the order the shell processes the various expansions and quotings. If you directly type

```
find . -name "foo*"
```

The shell will remove the quotes and pass `foo*` as parameter to `find`.

Without the quotes, the shell would perform the globbing for the `*` first, potentially resulting in multiple matches that would confuse `find`. So it's wise to use the quotes.

But if you `read` the string from a file, the variable will contain the quotes. Now, when you do

```
> echo $LINE
"foo*"
> echo "foo*"
foo*
> find . -name $LINE
```

you see that the quotes of `$LINE` will not get removed opposed to the ones for `echo "foo*"`. This is because the shell first handles the quotes of `echo $LINE` (there aren't any) and then performs the variable substitution, so the line will read `echo "foo*"`, but now the quotes remain.

So your `find` will look for files containing the quotes. The solution is to leave away the quotes in the file. No quoting is needed there, the complete line will go to the variable.

Comment: Yeah I understand that part. I tried it out also but still got no result. Can you provide an example script?

Comment: With exactly your script I get results by simply leaving away the double quotes in the file.

Comment: Now I get this error:

`$ /path/source/fn.sh: line 6: fnames.txt: No such file or directory`
I'm running the script through different directory. That's why it can't find fnames.txt. I tried writing the full path in the script after done, but still is says that error.

`done < /path/source/fn.sh`

Comment: You mean `done < /path/to/your/fnames.txt`, I suppose? I it says this file can't be found, there is a good chance it's not there! Also don't forget to adjust the path for `find` with the directoy to search for.

Comment: My script is now up and running! Thanks :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Please take a moment to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `IFS` to read as :

```
while IFS=\" read -r x LINE x; do
   find . -name "$LINE"
done < fnames.txt
```

This will ** essentially strip away the quotes ** and the `$LINE` will be what you need the `find` to work properly. What it does is split the line read in on quotes and so they thence won't show up in $LINE.